# No se que tengo que haceren este caso

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2019

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que se hacer, estaba haciendo un programa en Windows Forms C# en Visual Studio 2019 y al ejecutar aparece esto

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Creo que puede ser esto: Un `form` se compone de 2 archivos, cada uno con una  parte de la clase (clases parciales). El primer archivo es el que tu editas, y el otro se edita automáticamente a partir de los cambios que tu haces en el Editor visual. Me parece que este error aparece cuando tienes ese archivo abierto y modificas visualmente.